# Typescript .push showing. Argument of type 'T[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T' error

Tags: typescript

Can somebody please explain like I'm 5 why the `push` method is throwing an error please?

```
export function chunkArray<T extends []>(array: T[], n: number): T[] {
    const copy: T[] = [...array]
    const result: T[] = []

    while (copy.length) {
        const num: number = Math.ceil(copy.length / n--)
        const item: T[] = copy.splice(0, num)
        result.push(item) // error
    }
    return result
}
```

I thought I have the logic right but Typescript is showing the following error:

`Argument of type 'T[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'`

A solution would be *super* helpful too :-) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result` is defined as `T[]` but you're pushing items of type `T[]` into the `result` array.

`result` should rather be defined as `T[][]` (or `Array<T[]>`, should also work). The function return type should be changed in the same way.

Answer (score 0):

`splice` returns an array, so a T[], then you get the error that explains what is going on.

You're pushing an array on that line.

Answer (score 0):

Answer

```
export function chunkArray<T extends []>(array: T[], n: number): Array<T[]> {
    const copy: T[] = [...array]
    const result: Array<T[]> = []

    while (copy.length) {
        const num: number = Math.ceil(copy.length / n--)
        const item: T[] = copy.splice(0, num)
        result.push(item)
    }
    return result
}
```